# Ensuring `git merge` removes unneeded files

Tags: git

In git I have created branch1 from master. In branch1 I did some cleanup and removed some unnecessary files. So I go back to master and try to merge branch1 into it.

My problem is that the merge is not identifying conflicts regarding the files that were removed in branch1. How do I tell merge that I don't want those files anymore? Or how do I cause merge to operate manually so I can control this process?

I have looked at merge options like ours and theirs but I'm not sure I really want to favor one branch or the other. I just want more manual control in the review process.

I tried --no-commit but the file removal in branch1 just isn't coming up as any sort of conflict to merge.

I'm new to git so maybe there's a completely different way I should be doing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you expect a conflict? If these files haven’t been modified on _master_ after _branch1_ diverted, no conflict should happen. These files should be marked as deleted in `git status` after issuing `git merge --no-commit`.

Comment: i guess I expected a conflict due to the fact that master has a file in it that branch1 does not. After `git merge --no-commit` I ran `git status` and the file wasn't marked as deleted. The file was still there. Should I just checkout master and do a `git diff` with branch1 and manually delete files as needed and then do a commit?

Comment: have you actually tried to do the merge? If not - please do the merge and come back to us if you still have problems.

Comment: Yes, i setup some test repositories to try it. If I don't modify the file in master and then merge in branch1 the file gets removed on master. But if I modify that file on master before merging in branch1 then I must resolve the conflict. What I really wanted was a merge switch to force a manual review of each change of the merge. Should I just run diff and checkout commands from the branch1 and manually setup the working directly to look just as I want it modifying or removing files as needed. Then commit changes to master and finally do a merge --ours with branch1. Thoughts?